# Can a Derby database simply be restored by copying a backup to the original location?

Tags: derby

According to the [Derby documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminhubbkup12677.html), a offline backup of a database can be created by copying the directory of the database.

There's a description of how to [restore](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/tadminhubbkup44.html) or [recreate](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/tadmincrtdbbkup.html) a database, but both assume that this is done by adding a parameter to the database url.

I'm wondering, if it is not much easier to stop the database server, remove the current database and replace it with the backup.

I have tried this and it seems to work. Are there any drawbacks to this method?

Comment: I think copying the folder is fine, so long as you indeed stop the database server first.

Comment: I've also done this and its worked. The docs might assumes we want to use "roll forward recovery" (db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminrollforward.html), but I'm still curious why they don't mention the possibility of directly replacing the files with the backup.

Comment: Bryan and trooper: Thanks for your comments - I've done this as well a couple of times and have not encountered a problem so far.